# List Azure Virtual Machines via REST API

Tags: rest, azure

I am currently attempting to get a list of all of the Virtual Machines that I have running under a Windows Azure subscription programmatically. For this, I am attempting to use the Azure REST API (https://management.core.windows.net), and not use the power-shell cmdlets.

Using the cmdlets I can run 'Get-AzureVM' and get a listing of all of the VM's with ServiceName, Name, and Status without any modifications. The problem is that I cannot find anywhere in the documentation of how to list out the VMs via the API.

I have looked through the various Azure REST API's but have not been able to find anything. The documentation for [VM REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj157206.aspx) does not show or provide a list function.

Am I missing the fundamentals somewhere?

```
// Create the request.
            // https://management.core.windows.net/<subscription-id>/services/hostedservices
            requestUri = new Uri("https://management.core.windows.net/"
                                 + subscriptionId 
                                 + "/services/" 
                                 + operation);
```

This is what I am using for the base of the request.  I can get a list of hosted services but not the Virtual Machines.

Comment: You can dive into the PowerShell cmdlets themselves and see exactly how they are doing it.

Answer (score 7):

You would need to get a list all the Cloud Services (Hosted Services), and then the deployment properties for each.  Look for the deployment in the Production environment/slot.  Then check for a role type of "PersistentVMRole".

VMs are really just a type of Cloud Service, along with Web and Worker roles.  The Windows Azure management portal and PowerShell cmdlets abstracts this away to make things a little easier to understand and view.

Comment: Right - take a look at `Get Hosted Service Properties` - documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460806.aspx).

Comment: Actually, when I list all the services, the VMs are not listed. Only the items that show up under 'Cloud Services' in the web based control panel. They have distinct names, so I am sure of this.

Comment: Any ideas why they have not provided direct API for getting VM because for setup having more than 500 cloud services it will take a lot of time to get the VM list.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps for listing VMs:

1. List HostedServices using  the following [ListHostedServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460781.aspx)
2. For each service in from the above, 
   a)[GetDeployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460804.aspx) by Environment(production or staging). 
   OR
   b) Get Deployment By Name.
3. In either case, get the value for Deployment.getRoleInstanceList().getRoleInstance().getInstanceName().

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure node SDK to list out all VMs in your subscription

computeClient.virtualMachines.listAll(function (err, result))

More details on Azure Node SDK here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/compute-node-manage-vm