# How to get list of Virtual Machines in Azure when the VM are powered off

Tags: powershell, azure

I went through similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693277/list-azure-virtual-machines-via-rest-api) and tried it. But the solution works only in case VM is up and running. Does anyone knows way to get the list even when VM are powered off.
I have tried using PowerShell and it works properly but i need to do same using Java Code.

Comment: Since Virtual Machines are listed using Service Management API, I don't think it has to do anything with VMs being powered off. As long as your code for consuming Service Management API is correct, you should be able to list VMs.

Comment: Hi @GauravMantri I again tried and compared the XML outputs. When the VM is off <Deployments/> tab is empty and when VM is ON then i get a lot of details including <RoleType>PersistentVMRole</RoleType> which tells me that it is a VM and not just cloud service.
Please let me know if the way mention in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693277/list-azure-virtual-machines-via-rest-api to get list of VM is correct

Comment: I just shut down the VM through the portal and fetched cloud service properties and got `<Deployments>` element in the response body. How are you powering off the VM?

Comment: I got the issue. Please check my answer. I was using the wrong x-ms-version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the issue was with x-ms-version.I was using an older date 2012-03-01. When i used 2013-10-01 it started working properly.